# Upgrading drools from 7.23.0.Final to 7.73.0.Final giving error Session Closed

Tags: java, drools, spring-framework-beans

Hi I am trying to upgrade drools-compiler, drools-core, and other drools components like drools-core-dynamic, drools-decisiontables etc from 7.23.0.Final to 7.73.0.Final. But I keep getting the below error :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

Let me know how to resolve this. I am using following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Drools abandoned proper semver and began introducing breaking changes with minor version increments in 7.44. You're crossing that boundary, and being bitten by at least one of these issues.

You need to review the release notes for all intermediate releases between your original and your target version. At minimum, you're missing a dependency (`drools-engine` or `drools-engine-classic`) from the 7.45 release. Note also the descoping of the eclipse compiler (if relevant) in 7.47.

Unfortunately you've got so many exclusions going on that I'm not entirely sure *what* you're trying to do, or what you're trying to work around, so beyond pointing you at the documentation there's not much more guidance I can offer in terms of upgrade compatibility.

The release notes for each release are the "New and Noteworthy in XYZ" sections at the end of the official documentation:
https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues when trying to upgrade and the workaround was to remove both `drools-compiler` and `drools-core` and use `drools-engine-classic` instead. As mentioned in a previous comment, starting with 7.45 they did added some breaking changes, see https://docs.drools.org/7.45.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#droolsreleasenoteschapter